# Comma usage in complex sentences with 2 conjuctions

Tags: commas, conjunctions, complex-sentences

TL;DR - Can we use 2 commas if there are 2 conjunctions in a sentence.

Hi Everyone,

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I need to know if the comma usage in the following sentence is correct. I would also also appreciate if you can suggest a better way of writing this sentence.

> I'm already at the Senior Consultant level, but I have seen different
> titles at different companies, so this will help me evaluate the fit.

Comment: It’s common enough in informal writing or speech, but I would avoid it in anything formal, such as when seeking a professional job. Your “so” clause works fine as a separate sentence.

Comment: @StephenS - Thanks for your reply. So the following comma usage looks okay to you? I really appreciate your help with this.


Do you know the compensation range for this role? I'm asking as I'm already at the Senior Consultant level, but I have seen different titles at different companies. So this will help me evaluate the fit.